# Precise columns to write data

Tags: java, jtable, tabular

I have 9 columns and I calculate some data in loop and I want write data in different columns, how I can precise for which column data is? I want change column if (wynik <2), but table.setValueAt isn't helpful because it's writing date in the same cell

This is what I want:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/vHIiN]

This is what I get:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/qG3pv]

There is section from my code:

```
int[] arr = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
              20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35,
              36, 37, 38, 39, 40 };

double[] walce = { 257.175, 263.525, 304.8, 323.85, 333.375, 396.875, 415.925,
                   454.025, 638.175 };
int w = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    wynik = (walce[w]/arr[i])-wartoscWysokoscEtykiety;

    model.addRow(new Object[]{
        wynik,
    });

    if (wynik < 2) {
        table.setValueAt(wynik, i, w);
        w = w +1;
        i=0;
    }
```

There is my whole code: [wklej.org/id/3057183/](http://wklej.org/id/3057183/).

Comment: I don’t quite get your requirement. Could you indicate precisely how you would like your data to appear in your `JTable`, please?

Comment: Resetting `i` — your loop control variable — to 0 is dangerous and sure to produce unreadable code. Will your loop ever terminate?

Comment: Also how is your code’s current behaviour different from the desired? Please be specific.